# Bullet points on listed items unaligned

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

So I have probably an easy question to answer...

I am working on the site [fairhopemicrocottages.com](http://fairhopemicrocottages.com), and on the "About" page, the bullet points using the "li" tag are not aligned properly.

I want the bullet points to be on the first word, not in the middle of the 2 sentences. Very annoying.

This is definitely caused by the fact that I took this site design from another site I found, and worked around the CSS, but cannot edit the CSS. (Or can I?)

If someone can help me with a work around to solve this problem, that would be great! Thanks!

Bonus question: On the front page, I like the picture I found, however it does not blend in well with the navbar text and my image, the text is hard to see for old people like my parents.

Is there a work around to change the color of that section at the top to black? Just so the text and image can be read easily?

Comment: post your code, don't link to website

Comment: Love the `#dreamweaver` tag by the way

Answer (score 0):

On line 56 in your stylesheet is something like this:

```
li {
    background: black url("../img/list.png") no-repeat scroll left center;
}
```

Change it to left **top**, and it moves it up:

```
background: black url("../img/list.png") no-repeat scroll left top;
```

But that's not good on your li's - they are too high then, so set a specific top like so:

```
background: url("../img/list.png") no-repeat scroll left 10px;
```

To fix the issue in your top nav to change it to black, just add background to that section:

```
#slideshow header, .black header {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: the stylesheet is attached to.. http://16powerhouse.com/wp-content/themes/subspace_theme/style.css

Maybe I am missing something, but is there a way I could edit this? Or perhaps extract it, and then have a local copy of the styles.css so I can change it to my liking?

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing default list bullets with a custom background and that background has a centered position, therefore:

```
li { background: url("../img/list.png") no-repeat left 11px; }
```

By replacing the `left center` with `left 11px`, your bullets will appear where you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could solve this by changing up your styles:

**Add this style:**

```
ul {
  list-style: url("../img/list.png");
}
```

**Remove this style:**

```
li {
  background: url("../img/list.png") no-repeat left center;
}
```